# Vertical Align Image Centering with Overflow:hidden

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; height:100px; width:100px;">
<img src="etc.jpg" width:"100px" /></div>
```

I've got an `img` into a `div`. The height of the `img` is undefined but it is bigger than the 100px of the `div`.

I want to vertical center the `img` and hide the top and bottom overflow.

Still I can't understand how to do this...

Daniele

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
 <div style="overflow:hidden; height:100px; width:100px;">
   <image src="etc.jpg" style="width:100px; position: relative; bottom: 25%;" />
 </div>
```

Hmmm the result is a bit weird when the image does fit

Comment: This only works if the height of the image is 100px. Otherwise it won't be aligned properly, as the percentage is evaluated based on the parent's property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the margin-top property of the image at a negative percentage. For example;

```
div img {margin-top: -50%;}
```

Just play with the percentage values and you should find something that works.

Comment: The negative margin should be based on the height of the image. But in this snippet, the percentage is applied on the height of the parent, which does not help. Adjusting the percentage will only fix the issue for one particular image whose height is constant, not for any image.